# how to compare modified rows and update into database using linq?

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I am working on [handsontable](http://handsontable.com/) with asp.net. If user changes data on table and click on save button. Data comes on Jason format through AJAX call. Then I am able to convert JSON format data to `List (of T)`. Till it is fine to me.

The problem is I will have `List (Of T)` but don't know which column is modified. So How can 
compare modified [row][column] with database row and if it is modified, how to update it with LINQ using Entity Framework?

```
 <OperationContract()>
    Public Function SaveGridData(ByVal input As String) As String 
        Dim initiativeData As List(Of InitiativeData) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of InitiativeData))(input)
        '' Update to database
        Return "ok"
    End Function

    #Region "Properties"

    Private _ClientIdx As Integer
    Public Property ClientIdx() As Integer
        Get
            Return _ClientIdx
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _ClientIdx = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _HierarchyIdx As Integer
    Public Property HierarchyIdx() As Integer
        Get
            Return _HierarchyIdx
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _HierarchyIdx = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private _CostCenterIdx As Integer
    Public Property CostCenterIdx() As Integer
        Get
            Return _CostCenterIdx
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _CostCenterIdx = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _LocationIdx As Integer
    Public Property LocationIdx() As Integer
        Get
            Return _LocationIdx
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _LocationIdx = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```